# is this a good way to call Junit assertions in a common method?

Tags: java, junit

I have written tests which call a method to find the missing number in a given 1 to n array. The test code is as follows:

```
public class MissingNumberInArrayTest {

    private int arrElements;
    private int[] arr;

    @Test
    public void mustReturnMissingNumberCase1() {
        // Given
        arrElements = 5;
        arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

        // When & Then
        callAssertion(arr, arrElements, 5);

    }

    @Test
    public void mustReturnMissingNumberCase2() {
        // Given
        arrElements = 5;
        arr = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5};

        // When & Then
        callAssertion(arr, arrElements, 1);

    }

    public void callAssertion(int[] arr, int arrElements, int expected) {
        // When
        int missingNumber = MissingNumberInArray.findMissingNumber(arr, arrElements);

        // Then
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, missingNumber);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have multiple cases to test and have used the assertion in common method which takes input and asserts the data. Is this a good way of writing tests?

Comment: When an assertion fails how will you know what was wrong without examining the stack traces? (it's not as direct as failure at line 10... - they'll all fail at same line and you have to walk up stack trace to where the call is, then go "ah that's what's wrong".

Comment: @MrR how do you know where they failed without examining the stack trace, even when the assertion is directly inside the test case?

Comment: What you are doing here is writing an assertion method like `assertEquals`, `assertSame` etc, just specialized for your use case. If this is the way you find clearest to express the intent of the test, it's fine; it's less common code than I would pull into a method, but that's personal preference. The only thing I would change is to name the method better.

Comment: @MrR JUnit tells you which test method failed.

Comment: @saka1029 - look at the code in that idiom they all fail in a method that is not the test method ...

Comment: @MrR JUnit doesn't tell you which non-test method failed.

Comment: I have deliberately added wrong info to one of the tests. When I run all tests, it shows error only for the test case with the wrong info. So, having these assertions is a good way, i believe?

Comment: This question doesn't have an exact answer. It's too opinionated. I wouldn't personally do it for simple cases like this. But there is nothing wrong with it in principle if it makes your life easier. A better solution for your example would be to use parameterized tests: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't have an exact answer (IMO), so it will probably be deleted soon.

I wouldn't do it for simple cases like your example but if it makes your life easier, I don't see anything wrong with it. You could rename the method as `assertMissingNumber` and it wouldn't be that much different than usual (although the method you really want to test is in the assertion call).

I think your specific example is perfect for parameterized tests, though.

This is what it would look like with Junit 4:

```
@RunWith( Parameterized.class )
public class MissingNumberInArrayTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList( new Object[][] {
                { 5, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, 5},
                { 5, new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5}, 1}
        });
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
    public int arrElements;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
    public int[] arr;

    @Parameterized.Parameter(2)
    public int expected;

    @Test
    public void mustReturnMissingNumberCase() {
        // When
        int missingNumber = MissingNumberInArray.findMissingNumber(arr, arrElements);

        // Then
        assertEquals( expected, missingNumber);
    }
}
```

You can check on the JUnit documentation [for examples with JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)